# jwt token authorization is not working properly with custom role

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-authentication

I am using **django-rest-framework** and default **auth_user** table of Django and I create new table to manage new user_role and I extend it using **auth_user.id** to manage more roles like ***(teacher, student, staff, admin, school)*** but Now In Django there is only 3 decorators permission_classes **(IsAuthenticated, AllowAny, IsAdminUser)** to authenticate different role users to authenticate user.

I am using below JWT Token Module in my Django App.

JWT TOKEN: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

**Solution which I think:** first make sure user is authenticated or login already, using ***IsAuthenticated*** decorator permission_classes and then I filter table and check user have enough permission to access specific route or not on basis of user role from extended user table

**ISSUE:** I need to filter data again and again in every route to check user role.

Please let me know best approach to manage this thing

Answer (score 0):

What you think the solution should be is how I would approach it. IsAdminUser is built into django-rest-framework but when using it with a JWT library, it makes more sense to only check IsAuthenticated. I am currently working on something similar in an application with multiple roles.

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ADMIN = 1
    MANAGER = 2
    EMPLOYEE = 3

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
        (MANAGER, 'Manager'),
        (EMPLOYEE, 'Employee'),
    )

    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, blank=True)

    # Other fields omitted
```

If your users can have many roles, you can create a role table and do a ManyToMany field. Once you get to your View logic, you could do something like this:

```py
# views.py

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenicated
from rest_framework.response import Response


class SomeApiView(APIView):
    # declare serializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
   
    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        if user.role != 1:
            return Response({}, HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        else:
            # get logic for requested view
```

Comment: Thank You. I will try to use this solution. Once It will work, I will update here

Comment: well in my case, I set many `boolean` to avoid choices in model. such as `is_admin`, `is_manager`